# What software tools to use for creating publication quality system diagram?

Tags: publications, graphics, online-publication

So far I have used powerpoint to create system block diagram or System overview diagrams and convert it to pdf to add in overleaf. Working with powerpoint is tedious. What other softwares are recommended for creating publication quality system block diagrams?

Comment: Try Inkscape.  It's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working in overleaf, the LaTeX tikz package would seem to be a natural choice.

The learning curve is a little steep, but there are probably system block diagram examples you can modify.

You can embed the tikz code in your document, or include it, or use tikz standalone to create a pdf.

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package